# About click events

Tags: jquery

This may have been asked already, so if it has, I apologize for the re-post, but I'm trying to get a button to append something to a document when a user pushes the mouse button down, then removes that something and returns to the original state when the user releases the mouse button.  How do I get something like that to happen?  Here's what I have so far.

```
var test = 'Hi';

$('#annun').on('mousedown', function(){
    $('body').append(test);
});

$('#annun').mouseup(function(){
    $(test).remove();
});
```

Comment: `append` is used with elements, on elements. `Hi` is not an element. `var test = $('<div id="hi">Hi</div>')` would work much better. (`test.remove()`)

Comment: `$('Hi')` is a selector.  It's looking for a `<Hi/>` element.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need an actual node, and not just a string. For just a plain textnode you can use the native method :

```
var test = document.createTextNode('Hi')

$('#annun').on({
    mousedown: function(){
        $('body').append(test);
    },
    mouseup: function(){
        $(test).remove();
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MCyFw/)

Comment: Works perfectly, than you.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are adding a string to an element which jQuery will convert into a `textNode` for you. The problem is jQuery will not know how to remove test when you call `$(test).remove()` so either you have to make `test` a textNode yourself or wrap it in an element. This will allow jQuery to interact with the textNode as it will have a correct reference.

Make test a textNode

```
var $test = $.parseHTML('Hi');//make textNode
```

Or make test an element

```
var $test = $('<span>Hi</span>');//make element
```

Then append/remove the jQuery reference to the DOM

```
$('#annun').one('mousedown', function(){
    $('body').append($test);
})
.one('mouseup', function(){
    $test.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few steps you'll need to take in order to do this:

1. On mouse down, create a node and place it in the document. In the example below, a span is created and placed within the div with id **content**.
2. On mouse up, clear the container holding the new node of all content. In the example below, jQuery's `.empty()` is called on the div with id **content**.

The above steps create the desired effect. See the code below and checkout the accompanying fiddle.

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button">Show Hidden Content</button>
<div id="content"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function () {
    var $content = $('#content');
    $('button').off().on('mousedown', function () {
        $('<span />', { text: "Argh! You found my hidden text!" }).appendTo($content);
    }).on('mouseup', function () {
        $content.empty();
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/86fUY/1/)**